# How can I add a custom error message by extending the Validator class in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I want to validate alpha_dash(Alphabets and Spaces) and the code below works fine

```
Validator::extend('alpha_spaces', function($attribute, $value)
{
    return preg_match("/^[a-z0-9 .\-]+$/i", $value);
});
```

but the error it gives is not user friendly :

```
validation.alpha_spaces
```

How can change this message?

This is the method where it is posts

```
public function create(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|alpha_spaces|max:255',
    ]);


}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add your custom error message as an array element to `resources/lang/xx/validation.php`:

```
'alpha_spaces' => 'The :attribute may only contain letters, numbers and spaces.',
```

Read more: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-error-messages